# DSolve implicit function of time

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

Apologies for the basic question.

I am trying to solve this differential equation for $w(t)$ as a function of $q(t)$: $$ \frac{dw(t)}{dt} = \mu_v \frac{R_{on}}{\delta} \frac{dq(t)}{dt}. $$
Solving with DSolve works fine:

```
DSolve[D[w[q[t]], t] == (Subscript[μ, v] Subscript[R, on])/ δ q'[t],
 w[q[t]], q[t]]
(* {{w[q[t]] -> C[1] + (q[t] Subscript[R, on] Subscript[μ, v])/δ}} *)
```

My question is how to impose the boundary condition $q = 0 \implies w = \delta/2$.  The naive approach gives me an error:

```
DSolve[{D[w[q[t]], t] == (Subscript[μ, v] Subscript[R, on])/ δ q'[t],
 w[0] == δ/2}, w[q[t]], q[t]]
```

Function: parameter specification `{q[t]}` in `Function[{q[t]}, δ/2]` should be a symbol or a list of symbols.

Comment: One problem is mathematical: If $w(t) = \sin t$ and $q(t) = t^2$, then $w(q(t)) = \sin t^2 \ne w(t)$.  Thus `D[w[q[t]], t]` does not represent $dw(t)/dt$.  I'm not entirely sure what you wanted, but given your first solution being "fine," perhaps this?: `DSolve[{D[w[q[t]], t] == (Subscript[\[Mu], v] Subscript[R, on])/\[Delta] q'[t], w[0] == \[Delta]/2} /. t -> InverseFunction[q][q], w[q], q]`

Comment: Yes good point.  Perhaps I am barking up the wrong tree here, DSolve might just be the wrong tool.  I have a relation between the time derivatives of $w$ and $q$ given by the equation in the question, and I want to integrate both sides with respect to time to get a relation between $w$ and $q$.  What I meant by "fine" is that it gives me the right relation, but perhaps for the wrong reasons given my derivative of $w$ doesn't make sense...  anyway, your solution does give me the answer I was expecting. I'm a little puzzled by the substitution of $t$ for $q^{-1}(q)$ though to be honest.

Comment: $q=q(t) \Leftrightarrow t = q^{-1}(q)$, abusing notation to treat $q$ as both a variable and a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, but given your first solution being "fine," perhaps this?:

```
DSolve[
 {D[w[q[t]], t] == (Subscript[μ, v] Subscript[R, on])/δ q'[t],
  w[0] == δ/2} /. t -> InverseFunction[q][q],
  w[q], q]
```

> InverseFunction::ifun: Inverse functions are being used. Values may be lost for multivalued inverses.
>
> ```
> {{w[q] -> (δ^2 + 2 q Subscript[R, on] Subscript[μ, v])/(2 δ)}}
> ```